# Deploying multiple web applications to a tomcat on single port 80

Tags: java, vue.js, tomcat, war

1. I need to host two websites on one tomcat server. Both on port 80.
   E.g.

A) abc.com
B) def.com both on one apache tomcat server.

I do have two folders named: abc-app1-apps and def-app2-apps instead of the standard webapps and webapps2 as I have read using folders starting with webapps may cause a conflict?

How do I do this?

2. I'm confused between appBase and docBase. one guide claims i need it, another claims I do not need it. Is there a good guide to this somewhere? I've tried looking at the tomcat reference but it doesn't provide examples.

```
    <Host name="abc.com"  appBase="abc-app1-apps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" reloadable="true">
    <Alias>abc.com</Alias>

    </Host>


    <Host name="def.com"  appBase="def-app2-apps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" reloadable="true">
    <Alias>def.com</Alias>

    <Context path="" docBase="."/>

    </Host>
```

Comment: Tomcat virtual host setup is pretty standard, check this https://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-use-virtual-hosts-in-tomcat you will get a fair idea

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the .war files you want in the same webapps folder.

For example, you could have two .war files: website1.war and website2.war and both websites working under the same port (80).